# Порядок вызова методов в Java

Tags: java

Вывод на консоль в данном случае получается `FileNotFoundException`. Как именно осуществляется выбор нужного метода для вызова?

```
public class Overload {

    public void method(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public void method(java.io.FileNotFoundException f) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
    }

    public void method(java.io.IOException i) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Overload test = new Overload();
        test.method(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компилятор выбирает метод, у которого тип параметра, вызывающего неоднозначность, наиболее конкретный (дальше от корня иерархии). В вашем примере `FileNotFoundException` -- потомок `IOException`, а `IOException` потомок `Object` (непрямой, через `Exception` и `Throwable`), т. е. крайний в дереве наследования -- `FileNotFoundException` -- он и будет выбран. Если классы находятся в разных ветвях иерархии наследования, будет ошибка компиляции. Попробуйте в своем примере заменить `IOException` на `EOFException` (тоже прямой потомок `IOException`), или `FileNotFoundException` на `String`, например -- компилятор вас не поймет.

Answer (score 2):

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the **most specific method is chosen**.

[JLS 15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)